# c# JSON REST response via 3 different approaches (WebRequest, RESTSharp, HttpClient) is empty, but Postman and browser works

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

When calling a specific endpoint in C# which works without issues in Postman (or via Firefox), I'm getting an empty response.

The url I'm calling is returning a collection of data. In the url parameters I can specify how much of said data I want.
I've inspected the response size in Postman, and when I limit the amount of data requested in my C# call such that the response is around 700kb, then I get a JSON response back.

However, if I exceed this size in the C# call, then the response is empty '{ }' and the ContentLength returned = -1 (the statusCode returned is 200, so this seems fine at least). This same request which fails in C# works fine within Postman and Firefox however...

I somehow suspect this occurs because either the deserializer's buffer is not big enough OR because the response is still in transit and the code somehow continues executing before it has read the whole response body...

See below for the 3 implementations which I've tested:

1:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
      using (var httpStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
      {
           using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpStream))
           {
               Info(await sr.ReadToEndAsync()); //Info logs the string to a file
           }
      }
}
```

2 (RESTSharp):

```
var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest(requestUrl, Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);
Info(request.Content); //Info logs the string to a file
```

3:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset-utf8";
var httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var binReader = new BinaryReader(responseStream);
const int bufferSize = 4096;
byte[] responseBytes;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
   int count;
   while ((count = binReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
   {
         ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
   responseBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
Info(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length)); //Info logs the string to a file
```

I'm not modifying the HttpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize property, but for good measure I've also tried changing this value, to no avail.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Postman can export the request to C# code. Can you try that code?

Comment: All of those approaches use HttpClient at the lowest level. All of them work just fine. 700KB is a very small file too. Besides, didn't you just say that even in POSTMAN you can get only up to 700KB back? It looks like the *service* rejects requests that would return more data

Comment: What is the actual response when that happens? What is the status code? The C# code simply ignores failures, it doesn't log them. You may be getting a 400 (Bad request)

Comment: There is a HttpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.maxresponsecontentbuffersize?view=netcore-3.1 ) Any chance you modified that property

Comment: "Besides, didn't you just say that even in POSTMAN you can get only up to 700KB back? It looks like the service rejects requests that would return more data"
@PanagiotisKanavos in Postman (or a browser) it works fine regardless of the size of the response. The issue only occurs in C# regrettably...

Comment: "What is the actual response when that happens? What is the status code?" @PanagiotisKanavos the statuscode is 200, however the ContentLength = -1

Comment: "There is a HttpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize property (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/… ) Any chance you modified that property" @derpirscher I don't touch this value and I've also already tried setting it to long.MaxValue, to no avail

Comment: "Postman can export the request to C# code. Can you try that code?" I'll try this, but to be honest I don't expect this to resolve the issue

Comment: Post the information in the question itself, not the comments. HttpClient works, with far larger responses. If it didn't, hundreds of thousand of developers would have noticed. I use HttpClient to make requests to unstable web services that return 1MB or even larger responses

Comment: Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually being sent and received, both with POSTMAN and your application

Comment: "Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually being sent and received, both with POSTMAN and your application" @PanagiotisKanavos I'll try, though I was hoping to somehow be able to resolve it without using Fiddler, as this issue occurs in a production environment. Nevertheless, I'll try and revert back here if I discover anything

Comment: There's nothing wrong with .NET or HttpClient. It looks like the *service* returns nothing. You'll have to see what's actually returned. It's quite possible you're sending a different request with POSTMAN too - cookies, headers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I've attempted to reproduce the issue locally in my own dev environment, but even with a far larger JSON response of 19Mb it works flawlessly on my own dev environment... So the issue seems to be environmentally related.
Do you perhaps have any ideas what might be causing this? I can't see any antiviruses running. Could there be some sort of aggressive firewall? I've not yet had the opportunity to investigate with Fiddler due to this being a production environment...

Comment: I've compared the response headers and I notice that the Content-Encoding response is empty (which makes sense I guess because the content returned is empty) compared to the Content-Encoding header from POSTMAN. All other response headers are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, it was being caused by the backend service to which I was connecting. Thank you again @Panagiotis Kanavos